# Critical points of Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry

How do you find critical points of an exponential map? I am working with a sphere of radius R.

I know that an exponential map maps vectors of the tangent plane to a neighborhood of the point Q on the surface (in this case a sphere). I honestly have no idea how to go about this an my internet search has been less than fruitful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with Jacobi fields and their relation to the exponential map?

Comment: Not really no. I know about Jacobi matrices. This particular question was the first time I have come across exponential maps.

Comment: I recommend you read the relevant chapter in a Riemannian geometry textbook - this topic is very standard and is covered in every introductory text I know.